# How can I reliably track the bottom of a dynamically updating HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've read similar questions on SO about how to do this, but my setup is slightly different and the solutions proposed on those questions, have produced a strange result.

On my page I have a `DIV`, whose height is fixed which I've given the ID `table-container`. As the ID suggests, it contains a table (`id="myTable"`), which has a row appended to the bottom every few seconds using JavaScript. The effect I am trying to achieve is that as the table grows in size, and beyond the size of the table container, the table-container `DIV` will scroll down so that the last row is always visible.

I've used the following JavaScript to achieve this:

`$('#table-container').scrollTop ($('#myTable tr:last').position().top);`

This works fine for the first 20 or so row additions, but after that it loses track of the bottom row completely. I can't figure out why it starts off so well, and then messes up.

I've created a JSFiddle which illustrates the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/crickes/meqzf4g1/16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you just do `$('#table-container').scrollTop ($('#myTable').height() );` ?

Comment: No reason at all <kick self>! Thanks. Curious to know why my original albeit over complicated way of doing it, didn't work reliably though.

Comment: Just tested it in my 'real' code and it works perfectly. I'm sure I tried this about 4 hours ago, and it didn't work, which is what led me down this over complicated path, but I must have had a typo in the code or something as it works perfectly now.